# How to build 64-bit Visual Basic.NET in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

Hopefully this is a simple question and I have just overlooked something somewhere...

I am writing VB.NET stuff in VS2010 on Windows 7 64-bit. It seems to build by default for a 32-bit target, how to I tell it to make a 64-bit executable?

I went to the project properties -> Compiler -> Advanced, but don't see the option anywhere.

Oh, and this is VS2010 Express, to be clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This involves using the Configuration Manager, it's not a part of the project properties.

Go to the Build Menu, then click Configuration Manager. Under Active solution platform, click New, then add one with x64 as the platform. Use this platform to compile for x64.

Comment: This is how to do it. Also, you first have to ENABLE the Configuration Manager, as follows:

Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General->Show advanced build configurations.

Comment: It should be there anyway, but maybe that's because I use the General layout for Visual Studio? Also, if an answer is correct, please click the check next to it!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have to go to Build -> Configuration Manager and create a new solution platform from the Active Solution Platform dropdown and select x64 as the new platform. That will also change your Active Platform to x64 from x86.

Damn, but Visual Basic will never cease to surprise me! Or is this the Principle of Least Surprise, VB edition: VB will surprise you when you least expect it!